# GetDIBits returns invalid colors array of compatible bitmap

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap, gdi

I'm, trying to take an array of pixels from compatible bitmap(it completly filled by `RGB(0,0,255)` color) throught `GetDIBits`, but it return another colors. And, when I try to change an array it actually returns an exception. What is wrong?

```
case WM_PAINT:
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    HBRUSH hb = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 255));

    HDC hdcc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    HBITMAP bm = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, r.right, r.bottom);

    SelectObject(hdcc, bm);
    SelectObject(hdcc, hb);

    Rectangle(hdcc, 0, 0, r.right, r.bottom); //filling by the blue brush

    BITMAPINFO bi = { 0 };

    bi.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(bi.bmiHeader);

    int er = GetDIBits(hdcc, bm, 0, 0, NULL, &bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
    //In GetDIBits, as HDC argument must be compatible, yes?

    if (!er)
    {
        cout << "ERROR HERE:"<< GetLastError()<<"ENDS";
    }

    COLORREF *buf = new COLORREF(bi.bmiHeader.biSizeImage); //Yet, still, I have not understood, which type array should be - char, BYTE, COLORREF or anything else

    bi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
    bi.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bi.bmiHeader.biHeight = abs(bi.bmiHeader.biHeight);

    GetDIBits(hdcc, bm, 0, bi.bmiHeader.biHeight, buf, &bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    for (int i(0); i < 100; i++)
    {
        cout << (int)GetRValue(buf[i]) << ",";
        cout << (int)GetGValue(buf[i]) << ",";
        cout << (int)GetBValue(buf[i]) << ",";
        cout << endl;
    }

    SetDIBits(hdcc, bm, 0, bi.bmiHeader.biHeight, buf, &bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    delete []buf;

    BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, r.right, r.bottom, hdcc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    DeleteObject(hb);
    DeleteDC(hdcc);
    DeleteObject(bm);

    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
}
break;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvGFV.png)

Comment: What is the result of `sizeof(bi.bmiHeader);`?  May need to _pack_ it.

Comment: _"but it return another colors"_ -- what color? _"returns an exception"_ -- what exception? C'mon don't let us waste our time by guessing.

Comment: @chux, it returns 40

Comment: @ArturKlochko See [bmp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format), I'd expect 14.  Likely need to post `BITMAPINFO` definition and provide other details for a [MCVE]

Comment: @zett42, I've added image, and the exception is - "Heap was corrupted"

Comment: @chux, didn't understood, You want me, to pin the `BITMAPINFO` definition to my post?

Comment: Look at your call to "new".  See anything wrong?  Like maybe using parentheses instead of square brackets?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, lol how could I make this mistake. Now it completly work, thank You)

Comment: In addition to PaulMcKenie's comment, be aware that biSizeImage might be 0, in which case you have to figure out what it should be.  Also, at that point biSizeImage may be the size of the device-dependent bitmap, which might be different than the size of buffer you need for the device-independent copy you're trying to get.  Finally, per the docs, the size is in bytes no COLORREFs.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with this line:

```
COLORREF *buf = new COLORREF(bi.bmiHeader.biSizeImage);
```

1. As @PaulMcKenzie pointed out, you meant to use square brackets rather parentheses so that you allocate space for an array.
2. `biSizeImage` is in bytes, not `COLORREF`s, so this over-allocates.
3. `biSizeImage` may be zero, in which case you'll allocate nothing.  When `biSizeImage` is zero, it means you have to compute the actual size necessary.
4. At this point in the program, `biSizeImage` is the size of the device-dependent ("compatible") bitmap, which may very well be different than the size you need for the device-independent data you're trying to grab.